# Node JS wait for asynchronous listeners before returning

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, asynccallback, icallbackeventhandler

I'm working on this API and I need this function to return a responseObject, but the value needs to be set by asynchronous listeners before returning. The problem is that node js returns them immediately before the listeners have a chance to modify the value of that value.

Is there something I can do other than a while(responseObject === undefined) loop to prevent the function from returning immediately?

Note : I haven't written the other switch statement cases yet.

```
exports.queryServer = function (useIPv6, databaseId, apiId, ipAddress, serverIp, timeoutDelay, port) {
var client = useIPv6 ? dgram.createSocket("udp6") : dgram.createSocket("udp4");
var transactionId = randomstring.generate({
    length: 20,
    charset: "alphanumeric"
});
var queryString = databaseId + ";" + apiId + ";" + ipAddress + ";" + implementationProtocolVersion + ";" + nodeJSAPI + ";" + transactionId + ";";
var responseObject;
client.on("error", function (err) {
    responseObject = "Socket error : " + err;
});
client.send(queryString, 0, queryString.length, port, serverIp, function () {
    console.log("Querying Server : " + queryString);
});
var timeoutObject = setTimeout(function () {
    client.close();
    //alert user/throw error here
    console.log("Error : Request timed out after " + timeoutDelay + " milliseconds");
    responseObject = "Error : Response timed out after " + timeoutDelay + " milliseconds";
}, timeoutDelay);
client.on("message", function (message) {
    client.close();
    clearTimeout(timeoutObject);
    var msg = message.toString();
    var responseArray = msg.split(";;")[1].split(";");
    switch(databaseId){
        case 12:
            responseObject = new na_proxy(responseArray);
            break;

    }
    console.log("Server Response : " + msg);
});
return responseObject;
```

}

Comment: *Is there something I can do other than a while(responseObject === undefined) loop to prevent the function from returning immediately?* — No, and that won't work either (the asynchronous functions will never fire while the event loop is busy running the while loop)). You can't return from an asynchronous function.

Comment: What options do I have to return the data to the user other than using a console.log() statement in the asynchronous functions?

Comment: See the duplicate question.